# Goog apps script not working?

Tags: google-apps-script

I started google apps script today, but I found out that many things are not working for example: Date methods and this:

```
function myFunction() {
   var now = new Date();
   var twoHoursFromNow = new Date(now.getTime() + (300 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
   var events = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa@group.calendar.google.com").getEvents("2018-04-03", "2018-04-10");
//   Logger.log('Number of events: ' + events.length);

   doGet(events.toString());
}
```

This error is given: Cannot find method getEvents(string,string). (line 4, file "calender")
When execute the script I only get

```
[object Object]
```

I run it as a web app.
Is this me or Google apps script?

Answer (score 1):

According to GAS documentation, the method 'getEvents()' accepts 2 parameters of type 'Date'. In your example, both parameters are of type 'string'.  Try substituting both string parameters with your 'now' and 'twoHoursFromNow' variables.

More info
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#getEvents(Date,Date)